# Solr boost not working after upgrade to 9.4

Tags: solr, solr-boost

Booster ain't working after ugrading from solr 7.7 to 9.4:

```
q={!boost b=recip(ms(NOW,created),3.16e-11,1,0.1)}sorlrocks
```

Parsed query:

```
parsedquery_toString="+(+(text:boost) +(text:b) +(text:recip) +(text:ms) +(text:now) +(text:created) +(text:3) +(text:16) +(text:e) +(text:11) +(text:1) +(text:1) +(text:sorlrocks))"
```

but it should be:

```
parsedquery_toString="+(+FunctionScoreQuery(+text:sorlrocks, scored by boost(1.0/(3.16E-11*float(ms(const(1702494601715),date(created)))+0.1))))"
```

My guess is that query is not parsed properly and I checked plugins/libraries/configuration/etc. no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like edismax does parse booster from local params and booster function needs own query string parameter `qb`:

```
q=sorlrocks&qb=recip(ms(NOW,created),3.16e-11,1,0.1)
```